# join user input at index of inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I can't seem to figure out why I can't get this loop to loop - it always breaks instead. I believe if it was looping, the script (hopefully) would be working as instructed.

I've attached the instructions to the script and inline to explain my thinking.

Tahnks!

script accepts user inputs, and every time script receives a string, it should add the string to a growing string. Newly added strings should be added to the growing string at the index equal to the newly added string's length. If the newly added string's length is equal to or larger than the growing string, this script should add the new string to the end of the growing string. When this script receives a blank input, this application should stop receiving input and print the growing string to the console.

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
user_word = input()
second_word = input()
results = user_word + second_word[:]
i = results
while results == "":  # When script receives a blank input
    print(results)  # stop receiving input and print the growing string
    break

if user_word >= results:  # if newly added string length equal to or larger
    results = user_word + second_word[:]
    user_word.join(results)  # the new string added to end of the growing string.
    print(results)

if user_word < results:  # new string is shorter than the existing string THEN
    results = user_word + second_word[:]  # add the new string at the index equal to the new string length.
    user_word.join(results)  # Newly added strings should be added to the growing string
    print(results)
```

Comment: its not even indented properly how would it work?

Comment: do you understand my answer?

Comment: I think for some reason the indenting got screwed up when I pasted it. it was actually formatted right before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = ''

while True:
  user_word = input('Enter string')
  if len(user_word) >= len(s):
    s = s + user_word
  elif user_word == '':
    print(s)
    break
  else:
    s = s[:len(user_word)] + user_word + s[len(user_word):]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Explaining the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code. It helps the author and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves while giving them the clues to the knowledge they need to expand their programming skills.

Comment: the op clearly understands it, or would have said something @Ironkey

Comment: that assumption is not true at all, they could be trying to figure out how it works at this very instant

Comment: the user was seen 57 minutes ago, I answered 2 hours ago. Since this is an expert topic I assumed the op understood. But I will ask the op if they need explanation @Ironkey

Comment: there we go they accepted. **but** for future reference, you're not only answering the OP, you're answering everyone else who comes to the site looking for an answer to this problem. So its better to add explanation anyways. Congrats on the accepted and happy coding :^)

Comment: @Ironkey yeah I totally agree, it was just that this question was quite simple logic, I thought an explanation was redundant

Comment: true, maybe the slicing operation (which seems to be really the center of what you're doing at a glance) could be explained.

Comment: @Ironkey Yeah that true